# Cannot access the right class/id with PHP Simple DOM Parser

Tags: php, parsing, dom, web-scraping

I want to access the following element with PHP Simple DOM Parser:

```
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-committees" role="tabpanel">
```

and then access the table after it.

But there are other elements on the page, that use the same class. For example:

```
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-dates" role="tabpanel">
```

So I need to specify both the class AND the id as a selector, to ensure that I can access the right table.

My current code is as follows.

```
function getCommittee($url) {
    //echo "Processing URL: $url<br>";
    $html = file_get_html($url);
    $rtnArray = array();

    $item = 0;
    foreach($html->find('.tab-pane') as $element) {
        if($item == 4) { // as this is the fourth time '.tab-pane' appears on the page
            foreach ( $element->find( '<tr>' ) as $c ) {
                if ( $item == 4 ) { // As this is the fourth time '.tab-pane' appears on the page
                    array_push( $rtnArray, $c );
                }
            }
        }
        $item++;
    }
    return $rtnArray;
}
```

As you can see I have tried a workaround by counting the number of times I have seen the class, which works, but some pages break this.

An example URL is:

https://waset.org/aeroengines-conference-in-september-2020-in-amsterdam

Any ideas how I can code this robustly in PHP Simple DOM Parser?

Thanks

G

Comment: Why not just use the `id` as the selector? Since it should be unique that should resolve your issue.

Comment: Thought of that :-). It is not unique, it also appears on the page as:

    <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-committees-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-committees" role="tab">Committees</a>

Comment: That looks like a different `id`: `nav-committees-tab` not `nav-committees`. Either way, you could qualify the `id` with the tag e.g. `div#nav-committees` or combine with the class e.g. `.tab_pane#nav-committees`

Comment: Ahhhh - why did Ai not see this. Let me try that later (don’t right now)

Comment: That worked, thank you. Should have spotted that.

Comment: Good to hear. Given the nature of the solution you may as well just delete the question...